# Multiple python sessions with IDLE

Tags: python, arcgis, python-idle

Is it possible to run more than one python script at the same time?   I try to start a second instance of IDLE, however I get an error message:

> "Socket Error:  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."    and then  "IDLEs subprocess didn't make a connection...."

Thanks

Comment: Indeed SO would be better for the question, though the answer is YES - you can run multiple python scripts at the same time. However, if you want to use multiple IDLE's - there is a problem. I do not have an anwser for you, but I remember that I could run two IDLE's in the past, but now I can't! Without any major changes on PC.

Comment: I have ended up running python scripts in a CMD shell, while editing others in IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up running python scripts in a CMD shell, while editing others in IDLE.   There's probably a better way, but this works.